# Batch update failure with HTTP status code 404; discarding 1 replication tasks

Tags: spring-security, spring-cloud, netflix-eureka, netflix-zuul, spring-cloud-netflix

After starting the service discovery, When the proxy microservice is registered, the eureka is throwing the following error:

```
2020-06-11 21:07:19.778 ERROR 1040 --- [et_localhost-19] c.n.e.cluster.ReplicationTaskProcessor   : Batch update failure with HTTP status code 404; discarding 1 replication tasks
2020-06-11 21:07:19.778  WARN 1040 --- [et_localhost-19] c.n.eureka.util.batcher.TaskExecutors    : Discarding 1 tasks of TaskBatchingWorker-target_localhost-19 due to permanent error
2020-06-11 21:07:49.782 ERROR 1040 --- [et_localhost-19] c.n.e.cluster.ReplicationTaskProcessor   : Batch update failure with HTTP status code 404; discarding 1 replication tasks
2020-06-11 21:07:49.782  WARN 1040 --- [et_localhost-19] c.n.eureka.util.batcher.TaskExecutors    : Discarding 1 tasks of TaskBatchingWorker-target_localhost-19 due to permanent error
2020-06-11 21:08:11.629  INFO 1040 --- [a-EvictionTimer] c.n.e.registry.AbstractInstanceRegistry  : Running the evict task with compensationTime 0ms
2020-06-11 21:08:19.796 ERROR 1040 --- [et_localhost-19] c.n.e.cluster.ReplicationTaskProcessor   : Batch update failure with HTTP status code 404; discarding 1 replication tasks
2020-06-11 21:08:19.796  WARN 1040 --- [et_localhost-19] c.n.eureka.util.batcher.TaskExecutors    : Discarding 1 tasks of TaskBatchingWorker-target_localhost-19 due to permanent error
```

[Error Log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OtmEI.png)

The dependencies are as follows:

```
<properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>Hoxton.SR3</spring-cloud.version>
        <springfox-swagger2-version>2.9.2</springfox-swagger2-version>
        <springfox-swagger2-ui-version>2.9.2</springfox-swagger2-ui-version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
    
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-zuul</artifactId>
        </dependency> 
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-config</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
```

bootstrap.yml

```
spring:
  application:
    name: tng-crs-eureka            
server:
  port: 8761
  servlet:
    context-path: /eureka
eureka:
  client:
    registerWithEureka: false
    fetchRegistry: false
```

Any help is highly appreciated. I have tried by disabling the batch update tasks also. But, it didn't worked.

Comment: A single log statement is not helpful in trying to diagnose a problem. Can you include your dependencies (including versions) you configuration and steps to reproduce the problem?

Comment: @spencergibb I have updated the post with dependencies used.

Comment: @spencergibb Can you please help me with this issue?

Comment: You didn't add your configuration properties.

Comment: @spencergibb configuration properties added.

Comment: Why set a context-path of /eureka?

Answer (score 0):

Finally, The mistake that I have made was figured out. I have set the context-path of /eureka. And that is the reason for all this trouble. Removing the context path of eureka resolves the issue for my case.

Comment: I'm facing a similar problem but I never had the context-path set, any pointers on what else could be the issue?